# TimeFold.ai working on re-coding from timefold.ai schoolt timetabling to job shop scheduling for industrial production

Tags: java, maven, timefold

Goodmorning everyone, i'm working on recoding of timefold.ai school time tabling to create a job shop scheduling for industrial production, i "trasformed" Lesson class into Orders, Teacher into working operators, and group subject into product material using the same constraintProvider class and changing timeslot from 1 hour timeslot into 15 minutes timeslot, like that when i insert a new order into the DemoResource class I divide for example 3 hours production into 15 minutes slot so like that I suppose the programe should organize the orders on that characteristics.
When I run the program it work on 6 machine simultaneously but place in a 15 minutes slot more than one order slot.
How should I fix this problem?
another question... if i would like to pass a JSON file with my orders data to my timefold instead of using the DemoResource class, How could i do that?

This is my work so far:
https://github.com/EdoZp1/TimeFold-IndustrialProduction-EdoardoZoppi

Comment: You probably forgot to push your changes to the repo. I still see the original structure there.

Comment: You will probably see a version of school  timetabling which is modify for my purpose, Lesson is equal to Orders, Room is equal to Machines,  Teacher is equal to Worker and Group Subject to Product Materilal (we are talking about single material productions), when i finished the constraints i will refactor the names

Comment: Have you seen the food packaging quickstart? That's arguably closer than school timetabling.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if a solver gives you a solution in which there is a situation you don't like, you need to identify the situation and write a constraint to penalize that situation. In this case, you need to write a hard constraint to penalize every time the solver puts two jobs in the same slot. Something conceptually like this:

```
forEach(Order.class)
    .join(Order.class, Joiners.equal(Order::getSlot))
    .filter((order1, order2) -> order1 != order2)
    .penalize(...Score.ONE_HARD)
    .asConstraint("Two orders in the same slot.");
```

(Side note: I would be very cautious in applying the School Timetabling model to job shop scheduling. You will probably run into difficulties and will need to change the model, especially as you start trying to add dependencies between jobs. Unfortunately, we do not yet have a job shop scheduling quickstart for you to use.)

As to your JSON question, this is not directly related to Timefold Solver. You are effectively asking how to deserialize a Java object from JSON, and how to supply that JSON remotely; based on whether you're using Quarkus or Spring Boot, the answer will differ. But neither of the answers will be specific to Timefold Solver; I suggest you either Google for the answer, or ask another question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank u for trying helping me, yeah I know this recoding could be difficult to realize but its for my degree tesis report, its sperimental and i have to at less try to do it!

Comment: Using a new hard constaint was the first try I did, didnt work... in the code on my github theres the way I implemented it... talking about JSON, i'm using Quarkus, and i thougt that now my program is taking resource form the demoResource class, i was wondering if i can take for example a JSON gived by an ABP management system in which i would record my orders

Comment: as i said before, i tried to divide my orders into 15 minutes slot so that you could probably mange in a better way big time needed orders, but dont know why every orders stays like in one hour virtusal slot (for example it stays into: 00:000-00:15, 00:15-00:30, 00:30-00:45, 00:45-1:00) and in that way the orders 15 minutes slots overlap in a single time slot, theres like a 1 hour time limit per order in some way...